# Replacement fan+light switch wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I am in the process of updating/modernizing the switches in our home (DIY - I am not an electrician) and I have replaced an old fan/light switch with a knob for the various fan speed with a Lutron switch I found while bargain hunting that initially seemed like a good replacement, as it has a rocker switch for the light and a small sliding tab for the fan speeds, seeming similar in functional appearance to what I replaced.

I found the old switch was connected to 12/3 NM-B with black and blue wires to the red and black NM-B wires respectively, while two black wires from the opposite side of the old switch were to a shared neutral (ie all connected to the white wire in the NM-B for three wires in one nut).

I connected the new switch, which has black, red, and yellow wires (numerically matching the NM-B), as well as a ground. I connected the black and red NM-B wires to the black and red switch wires and the yellow wire to the neutral (white) so that the rocker switch activates the light, while the small sliding switch activates the fan as intended. The problem, however, is that **the fan can only be activated if the rocker switch (and therefore the light) is turned on**. The fan cannot be turned on independently of the light as it is currently wired.

My question is whether this can be corrected with the current 12/3 wiring setup and the switch I have, or do I need to buy a different switch? Thanks for any assistance or advice!

Comment: What model is your new fan switch?

Comment: Did your old switch allow independent operation of fan and light?  Do you have a neutral wire at the switch?

Comment: If the blacks from the old switch were connected to the white "neutral" in the cable, it sounds like this was a switch loop, and that the white wire really was _NOT_ a neutral. Pics of the original wiring and the new wiring would help.